# How to set the current date in the gnuplot title

Tags: date, gnuplot, title

It's possible to set the current date in the gnuplot title?

Something like...

set title "date of execution = `datetime()`"

Thanks in advance.

Alexandre.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `strftime` and `time(0)` to add a time/data to your title, e.g.:

```
set title "data of execution ".strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", time(0))
```

Alternatively, if it doesn't have to be in the title you can also use

```
set timestamp
```

Comment: The OP asked how to make it display the date.

Comment: @SDsolar Yes, and this is what I do in my answer. Well, I use a datetime, but according to the `datetime()` in the question this is what the OP actually wants, so where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct. Unfortunately, both `time(0)` and `timestamp` are UTC. You need to manually convert UTC to your local time zone. For example:

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d @ %H:%M:%S';                   # Format used for printing out time
time_diff=8*60*60;                             # Seconds between local time zone and UTC
curr_time_utc = time(0);                       # Get UTC time
curr_time_pdt = curr_time_utc - time_diff;     # Adjust to local time zone
print "Current time (UTC): ".strftime(fmt, curr_time_utc);
print "Current time (PDT): ".strftime(fmt, curr_time_pdt);
```

Comment: The OP asked how to make it display the date

Comment: 8*60*60 will not accurately work with summer/winter time. However it is good to know how to fiddle with the time format. So I could do this: `set output 'temperature.all_'.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time(0)).'.png'`

Answer (score 0):

I just added 8 hours in seconds to time to adjust for my Timezone of +8. 8x60x60 = 28800

set title "Last Run: " .strftime("%a %b %d  %H:%M", time(0)+28800)

Works a treat.

Bj